# get string from array to apply to labels

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, nsarray

I am fetching json objects.  Then filtering down to one object, this results in array of one object.  Here is a example:

```
company
companyname: richs diner
state: iowa
city: antioch

company
companyname: dines
state: california
city: LA
```

I filter the above to one company.
then filter to only apply the city to a label, but it appears you can't change the one word array to a string.

I want to apply each value to a label.  But I get the error below.
any ideas?

Here is sample code:

```
     - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray* getCompaniesArray = [json objectForKey:@"CompaniesCD"]; //2  get all company info

//NSDictionary* getCompaniesArray = [json objectForKey:@"CompaniesCD"]; //2  get all company info convert to dictionary insted

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"companyName = %@", selectedCompany];//added create filter to only selected state


NSArray *filteredArray = [getCompaniesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];//apply the predicate filter on the array


NSString *city = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"entityformSubmissionID"]; //print array to the string  //error
//NSString *city = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];//error
//NSString *city = filteredArray[0];//error

NSLog(@"here is your result: %@", city);//return result.  Works just fine

cityLabel.text = city;  //this does not apply the string to the label results in error

    }
```

My error is:

> [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fea5405f960 2015-12-28 21:49:58.027 J[3203:933300] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fea5405f960'

Comment: If you are getting corrected companyName then Update you predicate with "companyName == '%@'" This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to array with index. cant you access to array with key.

```
NSString *city = filteredArray[0];//index 0 or other index 
cityLabel.text = city;
```

Comment: Oh I have tried that and get the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Get string with index from array

Answer (score 0):

In this line …:

```
NSString *city = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"entityformSubmissionID"]; //print array to the string  //error
```

… you assume that `valueForKey:` sent to an array returns a string. This is wrong. It returns an array of the objects that are hold by the objects in the array with the key `entityformSubmissionID`. Okay, that sounds more complex than it is. (And it would be easier to explain if you had added an example to your Q.)

Let's say that the members of the array are dictionaries. Each dictionary has a value stored for the key `entityformSubmissionID`. Then you will get an array of that keys.

Example:

```
// The filtered array with 4 objects (dictionaries)
[
  // The first object
  {
    @"entityformSubmissionID" : @"A",
    …
  },
  {
    @"entityformSubmissionID" : @"B",
   …
  },
  {
    @"entityformSubmissionID" : @"C",
    …
  },
  {
    @"entityformSubmissionID" : @"D",
    …
  }
]
```

Applying `valueForKey:` would return an array of the IDs:

```
[
  @"A",
  @"B",
  @"C",
  @"D"
]
```

This is obviously no string. You can pick up one of these values:

```
NSString *cities = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"entityformSubmissionID"]; 
if( [cities count] > 0 )
{
  cityLabel.text = cities[0];
}
```